# I am not able to create dynamic element counter using js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a project which is a quiz. I have quiz arrays with choices and answer in them. I actually try to implement a page counter button to create a number and according to that number I want to add question arrays into my UI. But I am not able to see more than 1.

For example, when I click on any of my choice buttons it keeps continuing, and on the other hand with the page counter I want to handle my quiz questions array with the page counter, `quizQuestions[pageCounter]`.

My first value of counter is 1.

What is my mistake?

```
const answersBlock = document.getElementById("answers");
const pageCounter = document.getElementById("count");

 let q1 = new Question("What is the best programming language?",["Python","Javascript","C#","Java"],"Javascript")
    let q2 = new Question("which one is the Server Side Programming Lanugage?",["Python","NodeJs","C#","C++"],"NodeJs")
    let q3 = new Question("Which one is the framework of JS",["Laravel","Django","Vue","C#"],"Vue");
    let q4 = new Question("Which one is not code editor?",["VsCode","NotePad++","SublimeText","Python"],"Python")
    
    //Storaging the questions
    let quizQuestions = [q2,q3,q4];
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{

        //Loading the questions into Page

        UI.putQuestionsIntoUI(q1);

        //Playing around the buttons

        answersBlock.childNodes.forEach(element=>{

            if(element.nodeType === 1){
                element.addEventListener("click",()=>{

                    //console.log(element.textContent);

                    console.log("Clicked: "+ pageCounter.innerHTML +" times")

                    UI.nextQuestion(quizQuestions[pageCounter.innerText]);
                    
                    //Page Counter
                    //UI.increasePageCounter();
                    pageCounter.innerText++
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

UI.js

```
choicesToUI(answerObject){
        const answer = document.getElementById("answers");
     
        answer.innerHTML = `<button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[0]}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[1]}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[2]}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[3]}</button>`
    }
```

here is js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jh2qmb1w/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just move answer button event listener to choicesToUI function.

```
static choicesToUI(answerObject){
        const answer = document.getElementById("answers");
     
        answer.innerHTML = `<button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[0]}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[1]}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[2]}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">${answerObject.choices[3]}</button>`
    
    
       answersBlock.childNodes.forEach(element=>{
        if(element.nodeType === 1){
            element.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                //console.log(element.textContent);
                console.log("Clicked: "+ pageCounter.innerHTML +" times")
                //Checking the answer
                Question.checkAnswer(element.textContent);

                UI.nextQuestion(quizQuestions[pageCounter.innerText]);
                
                //Page Counter
                //UI.increasePageCounter();
                pageCounter.innerText++
            })
        }
       })    
}
```

and call choicesToUI in putQuestionsIntoUI function

```
static putQuestionsIntoUI(question) {
    //Gelen Paramtere Degeri Obje turundedir.
    console.log(question)

    const questionBlock = document.getElementById("question");
    const answersBlock = document.getElementById("answers");
    //Question
    questionBlock.innerHTML = `<p>${question.text}</p>`
    //Answers
    this.choicesToUI(question);
}
```

with these changes your code work perfectly :)
check this -> https://jsfiddle.net/kumnL9c4/